# What is the approximate per-server or per-cpu cost of WebOrb Java Enterprise?

Tags: java, apache-flex, weborb

I'd just like to know whether I'm wasting my time bothering to contact some annoying sales people, if it is out of our price range. This is most likely for deployment of a Flex/Java app in a clustered environment. Community edition is not going to work here.

Comment: -1 and a vote to close.  This is not a programming question.  You would have wasted less time contacting them than posting the question here.  http://www.themidnightcoders.com/company/contact-us.html#c1292

Comment: 100% guaranteed a simple "minimum price" will take longer to get than it would have been if someone just answered the damn question. But believe what you want.. this site is useless to people with simple one-line answer questions because of people like you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an insider I should say that our sales people are anything but annoying. You should get a straight-forward answer, but you should contact us directly using the following form: http://www.themidnightcoders.com/company/contact-us.html

Answer (score 0):

As a long time WebORB customer, I can tell you it is worth it...   It's performance, reliability, and feature set has yet to be matched, and it's constantly getting better.  I've also never interacted with any annoying sales people from this company, and generally the creator - Mark Philler, who commented above, is quite pleasant to work with.